# PayPal payment receipt shows wrong 'Payment sent to' email address

Tags: html, paypal

I use the PayPal Standard HTML API to take payments from a website into an account.
The website ‘form posts’ using the related account’s Merchant ID, e.g.

input type="hidden" name="business" value="ABCDEFGHIJKLM"

rather than the account’s primary or other email address.

For extraneous reasons I needed to add a new email address and make it primary. The previous primary address is still available as a non-primary.

Although all payments are received successfully, the Payment Receipt emailed to the buyer shows *‘Payment sent to [the old primary address]’* whereas the payment advice emailed to the account holder correctly shows *‘Payment sent to [the new primary address]’*

This looks impossible! Something somewhere is hanging on to the old primary... 
Any ideas please?

Comment: This sounds like a problem on the end of PayPal, not you, no? Contact someone at paypal, this doesn't strike me as code related, at least i don't think.

Answer (score 1):

I logged the issue with PayPal tech support who were extremely prompt in replying.

Apparently the 'Payment sent to' email address on the customer's Payment Receipt is taken from the 'Customer Service contact details' set up on the account and not from the name="business" value sent with the submitted HTML form.
(I also conclude that if there is no customer service email address set, PayPal uses the one set as primary when the name=business value is the Merchant ID.)
The Payment Advice emailed to the account holder is, or course, sent to the primary unless the name=business value overrides this with one of the account email addresses.

You live and learn!